# How to "connect" a SQLite DB to gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying out making websites with C# and I have a problem with my **SQLite DB**.

I've seen that you can Display every element of a DB with a gridview and it is automatic. But I cannot make it work with SQLite.

So I searched to find a solution to my problem and I found an article going through the process but it's a bit outdated.

He installed the System.Data.Sqlite(x86 x64) and I was trying to find that one but I couldn't find it.

But I found **System.Data.Sqlite.x64** and I assume that it's the same and that it just doesn't support x86 anymore.

[Nuget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ0oI.png)

Afterwards he opened the Entity Data Model and he had 2 options instead of 4 as me and also not the same ones.

I clicked on the EF Designer from database cause it had somewhat the same description as the one he clicked on.

[Entity Data Model Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1moa5.png)

After I click next I go to the **Choose Data Source** but I don't have an option for SQLite.

[Choose Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f2pj.png)

If I'm doing something wrong or I didn't understand something please correct me.

**Thank you for your time!**

Comment: hey, if you are creating a model with tables go with the sqlserver option, if it doesn't work try Nuget to install sqlite by Sqlite "team and Microsoft.Data.Sqlite

Comment: @Miguel Yeah I haven't actually tried the SQL server option. I created a simple DB with only one table with DB Browser. Will it prompt me to enter the path to my DB?

I will test in a bit. Thank you a lot though!

Comment: yes in the next step you will ask to connect the database and then choose which tables you want to load

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this was raised with Visual studio community: [sqlite-data-connection-not-appearing-in-server-exp](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/199172/sqlite-data-connection-not-appearing-in-server-exp.html)

Solution proposed is the following:

> Hi Robin,
>
> It appears the developer that created the SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox also has a solution to support VS 2017. See https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF6-workflow-with-SQLite-DDEX-provider

Or you can get the extention from the marketplace [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox)

> **Works with**
>
> Visual Studio 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017, 2019

Comment: Oh ok I see. 
I will try it out in a bit to see if it works well with the Gridview. 
Thank you for your quick answer and thank you for taking time out of your day for this question!

Comment: Cheers! Don't forget to accept/upvote useful answers!